Epson Perfection V330 Photo scanner drivers for Debian
I just got Epson Perfection V330 Photo scanner. Its a discontinued model and I'm trying to find drivers and software package for it. These page point to the software drivers:

The downloaded package "All-in-one package" Ver. 2.30.4(03-2023),it contains 'Image Scan! for Linux" driver bundle, and there also noted "The SANE package version 1.0.3 or later must be installed before installing Image Scan! for Linux".
The more recent "Epson Scan 2" 6.7.65.0 (06-21-2024) package is not available on that page, but found here. Which package I should to install for Debian 11?

Have you downloaded the one you can find and tried installing it? If so, what happened, is it not working as you expect? If you haven't, is there a reason you haven't done this yet?

I downloaded both packages, but which is correct for this model?

Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but it seems to me the correct thing to do is to install the package Epson notes is correct for this model, and if it doesn't work, proceed from there.

As @music2myear implies, installing the wrong driver is unlikely to cause harm. It might not work, or might only work for a subset of features, but just uninstall it and try the other, if it's not correct.

So the right package for my Debian is "Epson Scan 2" software. The installation was very smooth and fast.
